# Alert 3 months before the ending date

Tags: 7, views, rules

I am using the Views and the Views conditional modules to display an alert message 3 months before the ending date is coming, but it does not work. For example the ending date is 12/10/2016(m/d/Y) and I want an alert shows before that 3 months such as 09/10/2016(m/d/Y). So this is my views

[image]

This is my Views condition

[image: This is my Views condition]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're struggling with the issue about [Date comparison not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2032849).

You may want to try the steps explained in [Comment # 20](https://www.drupal.org/node/2032849#comment-11038035), to configure the timestamps.

If that doesn't work, then try what's suggested in [Comment # 19](https://www.drupal.org/node/2032849#comment-10998615), ie:

> Use the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module to format the date on the database server, prior to rendering by Views. This will allow for comparisons in Views Conditional.